# Difference between div#myid and div #myid

Tags: css, html-table

While I was doing CSS for a page I found that when I used to do `div#myid` then my CSS is applied to element and when I did `div #myid` it did not apply, but I don't think its a wrong, I have used it many times and it works.
Here below my CSS is correct but still first styling does not work and second works.

I have put a sample on fiddle here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin000/FnzNm/

```
table #tt
{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
table#tt
{
    color:yellow;
}


​<table id="tt">
    <tr><td>this is atable</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `div#myid` applies to a `div` element with `id` set to `myid`
- `#myid` applies to **ANY** element  with `id` set to `myid`

---

> i found that when i used to do div#myid then my css is applied to
>   element and when i did div #myid it did not apply

It works fine with both `div#myid` and `#myid`:

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FnzNm/1/)**

---

As for your tables ***there is difference*** between these two `table #tt` and `table#tt`. The **space** character plays important role here.

The `table #tt` means an element with `id` set to `tt` **inside** the `table` element at *any* nested level whereas `table#tt` means a `table` with `id` set to `#tt`.

**Examples:**

`table #tt` may mean any of these:

```
<table>
  <td id="tt"></td>
</table>

<table>
  <td><div id="tt"></div></td>
</table>

<table>
  <td><span id="tt"></span></td>
</table>
<!-- etc -->
```

So just any element with `id` set to `tt` **inside** `table`.

The `table#tt` only means this:

```
<table id="tt">....</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

First one said **#tt** inside **table**

```
table #tt
{
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
 <tr id="tt"><td>this is atable</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**&**

Second one said **#tt** with **table**.

```
table#tt
    {
        background-color:#ccc;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="tt">
 <tr><td>this is atable</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/FnzNm/3/

Answer (score 0):

`table #tt` is the element with id `tt` inside of some table (but not the table itself).

`table#tt` is the table with id `tt`

Since `#tt` is already unique, you don't need a more complex selector (unless there is some kind of logic going on along the lines of "unless the element has now moved out of the table because of some fancy DOM manipulation at runtime").